# How do I incorporate absolute value within my Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, absolute-value

| id | Impressions_Source | Impressions_Source2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15020 | 150201 | 151920 |

I am trying to figure out how to calculate a percentage difference (discrepancy) between two values utilizing absolute value.

Here is my formula used

`df['Discrepancy_Num'] = (df['Impressions_Source'] - df['Impressions_Source2']) / (df['Impressions_Source'] * 100)`

Would I just add .abs after?

`df['Discrepancy_Num'] = (df['Impressions_Source'] - df['Impressions_Source2']) / (df['Impressions_Source'] * 100).abs`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.abs()` afterwards:

```py
df["Discrepancy_Num"] = (
    (df["Impressions_Source"] - df["Impressions_Source2"])
    / (df["Impressions_Source"] * 100)
).abs()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      id  Impressions_Source  Impressions_Source2  Discrepancy_Num
0  15020              150201               151920         0.000114
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for

```
df["Discrepancy_Num"] = (
    -1 + df.Impressions_Source2/df.Impressions_Source
).abs()/100
```

since you can avoid accessing `df.Impressions_Source` twice. Indeed, the result is the same as yours, stemming from a rearranged formulation.

Comment: **Side note**: are you sure about the `df["Impressions_Source"] * 100` @Bo ? At first glance your calculation make me think to a relative variation. Something that [people usually do](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122554/is-the-percentage-symbol-a-constant) is *multiplying* ***the final*** *result by 100*, such that they can just attach a percentage symbol to it. If this is what you actually want to do, just replace ***my***  `/100` by `*100`.  But I may just be flat wrong: you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.absolute`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) function as well

```py
import numpy as np

df['Discrepancy_Num'] = np.absolute(df['Impressions_Source'] - df['Impressions_Source2']) / (df['Impressions_Source'] * 100)
```